# Raspbian Samba/Fstab file limitation

Tags: raspbian, samba, fstab

I'm connecting a HDD to the pi to share in my network. I setup SAMBA as directed, install ntfs-3g (my HDD is NTFS), then set specific UUID in `/etc/fstab` to the mountpoint located on my pi:

```
UUID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /home/pi/share/A ntfs nofail,uid=pi,gid=pi 0 0
```

where `share` and `A` both are `chmod 777`

Everything works, except when I transfer a file that exceed the size of the SD card that the pi runs off, i.e.8GB card will have ~4GB limit (4 goes to system files) or 16GB card will have around 12GB limit (again 4GB is system file).

Any idea how to resolve that limitation?

Output of `df -h`:

```
pi@TestPi:~ $ df -h /home/pi/PiMedia/A
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1 1.4T 692G 706G 50% /home/pi/PiMedia/A
```

Output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda1`:

```
pi@TestPi:~ $ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda1
Disk /dev/sda1: 1.4 TiB, 1500299395072 bytes, 2930272256 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6e697373

Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1p1 1936269394 3772285809 1836016416 875.5G 4f QNX4.x 3rd part
/dev/sda1p2 1917848077 2462285169 544437093 259.6G 73 unknown
/dev/sda1p3 1818575915 2362751050 544175136 259.5G 2b unknown
/dev/sda1p4 2844524554 2844579527 54974 26.9M 61 SpeedStor
```

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`:

```
pi@TestPi:~ $ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 1.4 TiB, 1500301910016 bytes, 2930277168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x29cc0ff5

Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1 * 2048 2930274303 2930272256 1.4T 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

## SOLUTION:

Summary - I created multiple folders (in one directory) to mount multiple drives for sharing. However, when sharing, I shared the one root directory of those multiple folders/mounted drives. This creates a problem where the OS sees that root directory belonging to the pi and inherits the file size limitation based on the SD card size.

e.g.
fstab mount drive usb1 --> /share/USB1; samba --> /share/USB1 ----- **WORKS**; no size limit

but:
fstab mount drive usb1 --> /share/USB1; samba --> /share ---- file size limitation exists

To fix this, you can mount and shared individual drives. But this would create multiple shared points on your network.

Or the better solution:
You can spoof SAMBA check for system space. Where SAMBA share will report a higher value than the actual space that is on the SD card.

edit smb.conf with

```
[global]
dfree command = /usr/local/bin/dfree
```

then edit dfree with

```
#!/bin/sh
df $1 | tail -1 | awk '{print 50000000" "50000000}'
```

Remember to give dfree permission.

This will trick SAMBA into thinking root directory has 50TB limit, thus removing the file size transfer limitation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87868/discussion-on-question-by-mathnerd18-raspbian-samba-fstab-file-limitation). Mathnerd18, please feel free to include additional information - as requested in the comments / now chat - into the question. If - for whatever reason - you are not able to join the chat, give me a note. Thanks.